# how to use count in MySQL in good properly way

Tags: mysql, count

I have 2 tables, this is my fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da5e4e/3

so basically i have 2 tables called personal and interview_score with personal.id = interview_score.personal_id.

assume this is my `personal` table

```
id  name
1   John Doe
2   Nian
3   Rijali
```

and this is my `interview_score` table

```
id  personal_id aspect_id
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   2   1
5   2   2
```

on this case, i just want to count how many personal_id in my `interview_score` table with this query

```
SELECT COUNT(i.id) as interviewed FROM personal p LEFT JOIN interview_score i ON i.personal_id = p.id GROUP BY i.personal_id;
```

but it returns just like this

```
interviewed
0
3
2
```

meanwhile, my expected result is just like this

```
interviewed
2
```

because on that table there are 2 personal_id based on that condition.

where my wrong at?

Answer (score 0):

You can use join instead of left join also you need to group by p.id

```
SELECT COUNT(i.id) as interviewed FROM personal p  JOIN interview_score i ON i.personal_id = p.id GROUP BY p.id;
```

from the above query you can get the count

To get count for a particular person

```
SELECT COUNT(i.id) as interviewed FROM personal p  JOIN interview_score i ON i.personal_id = p.id and p.id=1 GROUP BY p.id;
```